# Using URL pattern as /* in REST webservice?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, servlets, jax-rs

```xml
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

for my

```xml
 <servlet>
    <display-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
```

Servlet i.e the entry point of my app. In many examples I see everyone gives some path in the URL pattern but in my case I am just using `/*`. Is this ok? Or using some path in it has some benefits? Like faster URL matching? i.e the request if for the web service or so?

Comment: Yes, it is OK. It just depends on your needs. If you want to map to the root, the way is what you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it is not incorrect to have a /*.
If you have only one listener processing all incoming requests then what you have is absolutely fine. If you have multiple listeners/services processing different url patterns then of course, you will have different mappings for different url patterns.

I prefer to add a full url pattern like /path1/xyz/* if i know the pattern instead of /* so you i dont need to modify this mapping when i add another mapping/listener to process a different url pattern.